# sequence of functions and its limit

Tags: calculus

Let $f_n (x) = 1 $ if $x \in [n, n+1] $. And $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise. I want to find the

$$ \lim_{ n \to \infty } f_n $$

MY attempt: we know $  0 \leq f_n \leq 1 $ for all $n$ So $f_n$ is bounded. IT is obviously monotone since $f_n \leq f_{n+1} $ So limit exists. But I have trouble trying to see whether the limit is $0$ or $1$. Can someone help me see this last part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is not monotone. For example $f_{2}(2)>f_{4}(2)$ the way the sequence is defined. This sequence converges point-wise to 0 (Hint: If you fix an $x$ then you can pick $n$ large enough so that $f_{m}(x)=0$ for all $m>n$. To see this fix an $x$. Then by the Archemedian property there is a natural number $n>x$. Now because of the way the sequence is defined $f_{m}(x)=0$ for all $m>n$. For example $f_{n}(2)=0$ for $n>2$, $f_{n}(3.5)=0$ for $n\geq{4}$). It does not converge uniformly to $0$ and hence doesn't converge uniformly ($\|{f_{n}-0}\|_{\infty}=1$ for any $n$ and the uniform limit and the point-wise limit has to agree (see the proof of the theorem uniform convergence implies limitwise convergence)).

Comment: can you explain a little bit more how can we choose $n$ large enough?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hopefully it is clearer now.